# Android studio layout divided by 2

Tags: xml, android-studio, layout

please I need help to set the final layout to an item row list.

Here it is my actual layout:

[image]

I wish to have 2 textview on the left of the linear layout (edName and edSurname) and another layout with another textview (edAddress) that must set on the top of the purple layout.

Here is the xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="edName"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="edSurname"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:layout_gravity="right">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="edAddress"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please consider using a single RelativeLayout as the container for all your 3 TextViews. Nested layouts are bad for performances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="#00dd00"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="#dd0000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's perfect for me :)